# How to use xcopy with relative paths?

Tags: windows, command-line, xcopy

I've tried to use `xcopy` using relative paths and have had no luck.

I opened a command prompt as administrator. CD'd to my base directory where I want to `xcopy` a valid file from one location to another.

Steps:

```
cd c:\javascript_stuff\test\
xcopy "./editor/www/editor.js" "./rails/public/javascripts/editor.js"
```

I am prompted with,

```
Does ./rails/public/javascripts/editor.js specify a file name or directory name 
on the target (F = file, D = directory)?
```

No matter what I do I get `0 File(s) copied`. I've tried numerous permutations of the `xcopy` switch's with no luck.

To confirm, the source file `c:\javascript_stuff\test\editor\www\editor.js` and the target directory `c:\javascript_stuff\test\rails\public` both exist.

I was hoping to add this to a build script so the path should stay relative to the directory the command is executed in.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Ensure you are using backslash and not forward slash as in your example.

Comment: Oh man that was exactly it! Works perfect now.

Comment: I'll put it in an answer so this can be closed out appropriately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ensure you are using backslash and not forward slash as in your example.